# How would I edit Security Options ( In Local Security Policy ) through a powershell ISE script?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have looked everywhere for a script that does what I need. I really don't care if it is complex or simple. I just need it to edit multiple settings in security options. I'm in Windows 10. If anyone could help that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you look/search? Policies are registry changes. So, you can take that route. There are no built-in PowerShell local policy cmdlets.   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the normal registry cmdlets, since that is where these reside, but know that there are modules to help.

```
Find-Module -Name '*Policy*' | Format-List
```

Specifically

```
Find-Module -Name '*PolicyFileEditor*' | Format-List
```

Take a look at what they are doing and use as it or try and tweak as needed.

See also:

> [Manage Local Group Policy Objects from PowerShell and Desired State
>   Configuration](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/manage-local-group-policy-objects-from-powershell-and-desired-state-configuration/)

```
Get-PolicyFileEntry [-Path] <string> [-Key] <string> [-ValueName] <string> [<CommonParameters>]
Get-PolicyFileEntry [-Path] <string> -All [<CommonParameters>]
Set-PolicyFileEntry [-Path] <string> [-Key] <string> [-ValueName] <string> [-Data] <Object> [-Type <RegistryValueKind>] [-NoGptIniUpdate] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
Remove-PolicyFileEntry [-Path] <string> [-Key] <string> [-ValueName] <string> [-NoGptIniUpdate] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
Update-GptIniVersion [-Path] <string> [-PolicyType] <string[]> [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries. After you take a look, and if it resolves your use case, come back and mark this as you accepted answer for the benefit of others that may need this.